# Cannot reference Alice fixture in EntityContext following step (KnpLabs/FriendlyContexts) - Behat

Tags: symfony, behat, nelmio-alice, victoire

I use the really cool [knplabs/friendlycontexts](https://github.com/KnpLabs/FriendlyContexts) bundle to test [VictoireDCMS, a Symfony2 open source DCMS](https://github.com/victoire/victoire).

Actually, this is working pretty well in spite of the kind of my project (not a basic symfony-project architecture but a suite of bundles with a functionnal test application).

But... I'm now blocked to use alice reference in the EntityContext. The [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/FriendlyContexts/blob/master/doc/context-alice.md#entity-context) give these examples :

## user.yml

```
App\Entity\User:
    user-john:
        firstname: John
        lastname: Doe
    user-admin:
        firstname: Admin
        lastname: Admin
```

### my.feature

```
@alice(User)
Feature: My feature
    The feature description

    Background:
        Given the following products
            | name  | user  |
            | Ball  | John  |
            | Shoes | Admin |

    ...
```

This is really looking good and is exactly what I want to do and here is my code:

### template.yml [(full file)](https://github.com/lenybernard/victoire/blob/474d97d08c1327d4fb2754ffe302f44cd9b15f18/Tests/Functionnal/src/Acme/AppBundle/DataFixtures/Seeds/ORM/View/template.yml#L2)

```
Victoire\Bundle\TemplateBundle\Entity\Template:
    template_base:
        name: Base
        ...
```

### my.feature [(full file)](https://github.com/lenybernard/victoire/blob/474d97d08c1327d4fb2754ffe302f44cd9b15f18/Tests/Features/Page/create.feature#L22)

```
Given the following page:
    | name      | slug     | locale | template |
    | tatooine  | tatooine | fr     | base     |
```

Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work properly and I have this error when I run my feature :

> Expected value of type
>   "Victoire\Bundle\TemplateBundle\Entity\Template" for association field
>   "Victoire\Bundle\PageBundle\Entity\BasePage#$template", got "string"
>   instead. (Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException)

I can't figure this out and can't see any difference btw the example and my code... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When does the error appear?

Comment: The error comes when I run my feature with the behat bin

Comment: Is the website working correctly? Does the Symfony2 dev toolbar reports an ORM error?

Comment: Yes the website is working correctly and there isn't anything weird in the toolbar.

Comment: Do you have some news about this problem? I apologize for my previous comments, they were blatantly off-topic (there's no toolbar when running Behat!).